# Excel VBA / SQL Union

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to Join 2 separate columns from 2 different sheets to make a longer column from which i can then use a Vlookup from.

Sheet1
A, B, C, D, E, F, G

Sheet2
A, B, C, D, E, F, G

I want to Join(Union) Columns B from sheet1 and C from sheet2 together and find the Distinct values of the new list. I have been working on this for weeks.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ADO with Excel.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

''This is not the best way to refer to the workbook
''you want, but it is very conveient for notes
''It is probably best to use the name of the workbook.

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

''Note that if HDR=No, F1,F2 etc are used for column names,
''if HDR=Yes, the names in the first row of the range
''can be used. 
''This is the Jet 4 connection string, you can get more
''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

''Late binding, so no reference is needed

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


cn.Open strCon

''A sample query
strSQL = "SELECT Distinct A, B C FROM ( " _
       & "SELECT A, B, C " _
       & "FROM [Sheet1$] " _
       & "UNION ALL " _
       & "SELECT A, B, C " _
       & "FROM [Sheet2$] ) As J "


''Open the recordset for more processing
''Cursor Type: 3, adOpenStatic
''Lock Type: 3, adLockOptimistic
''Not everything can be done with every cirsor type and 
''lock type. See http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_open.asp

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

''Write out the data to an empty sheet (no headers)
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rss
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. Just one more thing. On Sheet1 the first 2 rows are header information, and sheet2 the first 4 are header information. any suggestions on how to exclude those?

Comment: HDR=Yes in the connection string will allow one header row, which will probably not suit, so perhaps change to HDR=No and add a range to the sheet, say "FROM [Sheet1$A3:C102] ". When HDR=No, you must refer to columns using F1, F2 ... Fn